# for range does not work: Is there a better way to get the pointers of the values of a channel?

Tags: go, pointers, channel

*Complete minimal example and link to Go Playground below.*

Due to the architecture of my software I have to pass a channel with pointers to a function. So I did the following (like in v1 in the full code) to convert the channel `from` to `to` and pass it to my function:

```golang
for packet := range from {
    to <- &packet   
}
close(to)
```

**However, when I later read from the `to` channel and dereference the pointers, I only get every second value and get it twice. So instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 I get for example 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5.**

But if i read and convert the channel using unconditional for loop and select case (like in v2 in the code), there is no problem:

```golang
for {
    select {
    case packet, ok := <-from:
        if ok {
            to <- &packet
        } else {
            close(to)
            break loop
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't expect that to make a difference. If I don't dereference the pointer in line 55, I see that it is always the same address that the for range loop uses for the variable `packet`. The result with the missing and duplicate values would then result from the fact that the values are read and output in parallel.

**Why is the address reused in the for range loop? Is this documented? (Edit: yes, it is. Thanks to @mkopriva! I had not read the statement in the docu) Is there a more elegant way to get the pointers of the values into a new channel than the solution using for loop and select case?**

full minimal code: [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/BdfytVZnJrA)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    // initialize sample channel
    from := make(chan string, 50)
    for i := 0; i < 50; i++ {
        from <- strconv.Itoa(i)
    }
    close(from)

    // invoke the test function
    to := make(chan *string, 0)
    go v1(from, to)

    // output
    for packet := range to {
        fmt.Println(packet, *packet)
    }
}

func v1(from chan string, to chan *string) {
    for packet := range from {
        to <- &packet
    }
    close(to)
}

func v2(from chan string, to chan *string) {
loop:
    for {
        select {
        case packet, ok := <-from:
            if ok {
                to <- &packet
            } else {
                close(to)
                break loop
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Why is the address reused in the for range loop? Is this documented?"* -- Yes, it is documented. To fix, you can do the following at the top of the loop's body: `packet := packet` (a new variable containing a shallow copy of the iteration variable).

Comment: https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_range *"The iteration variables may be declared by the "range" clause using a form of short variable declaration (:=). In this case their types are set to the types of the respective iteration values and their scope is the block of the "for" statement; __they are re-used in each iteration__. If the iteration variables are declared outside the "for" statement, after execution their values will be those of the last iteration."*

Comment: @mkopriva thank you! That works of course, even if it looks a bit strange at first. I also found it in the documentation now‍♂️

Comment: Note also that https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#channels says: *"It may seem odd to write `req := req` but it's legal __and idiomatic in Go to do this__. You get a fresh version of the variable with the same name, deliberately shadowing the loop variable locally but unique to each goroutine."*

Comment: It helps to understand that you can not get the pointers of the values in the channel, because the values in the channel are not addressable. You must copy that value _somewhere_ in order to take the address of that value. (also note that Go is experimenting with changing this semantic to stop people from making this same mistake https://github.com/golang/go/discussions/56010)

Comment: emphasizing @JimB's comment: since go 1.21, there is an experimental method to test for the "loop-var-bug": https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/LoopvarExperiment (also linked in the discussion #56010).